# Read csv file and put data in 2 seperate arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

I have a csv file with 5 lines, each line has 2 values separated by a comma

554, 234
233, 123
237, 143
983, 239
349, 183

I want to read each line and put the first value in one array and the second value in another array

So far I have got

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("csv file")
    .Add(line.Split(","))
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lines() as String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("csv file")
Dim a1(lines.Length -1) As String 
Dim a2(lines.Length -1) As String 

For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim values() As String = lines(i).Split(",")
    a1(i) = values(0).Trim()
    a2(i) = values(1).Trim()
Next
```

Comment: Doing some extra work on this code and am needing a regular expression. The value in the curly brackets e.g. [a-zA-Z]{2} means that it must have atleast 2. Is there a way to allow it to have more than 2 but no less. Sorry to post here but i'm a new user so I have post limits

Comment: @SimonJ I think it is `{2,}` - check https://regex101.com/ You can test your expression there and it also gives you expressions